# Rx - Where method causes memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, where-clause, system.reactive

I've created simple trigger based on Rx interval. It generates signal every specific interval and it is filtered by Where method like this (simplified example):

```
var isActive = false;

Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
            .Where(_ => !isActive)
            .Subscribe(_ =>
            {
                isActive = true;
                Console.WriteLine("New subscription item");
                Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000); // simulate time-expensive work
                Console.WriteLine("Finished");
                isActive = false;
            });
```

I would like to ignore elements when isActive flag is set to true. It seems to work because subscription block is called every 30 seconds (simulated time-expensive work) but when I profile such simple application I see tha many Action objects are stored into memory (~60-70 instances per second) and are disposed when they are being consumed by subscription block. I would like to ignore and dispose them immediately.

Comment: Keep in mind that Windows isn't able to run a timer every 1ms. The best it can do is about 16ms (from memory). Now 1000ms / 16ms = 62.5. That might explain the 60 to 70 instances that you get.

Comment: Try dropping a `.Synchronize()` call in after `.Interval` and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Are you sure there’s a memory **leak**? Sure, those observable objects are going to be created in a very quick succession, resulting in a lot of overhead, but they should be garbage collected when the filter discards them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I was able to reproduce this issue. The sequence below starts a timer that ticks every 10 milliseconds. The number of ticks are sampled every 3 seconds, and then are printed in the console along with the current memory usage. The total duration of the test is 5 minutes.

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
    //.Do(x => Thread.Sleep(1000)) // Uncomment this line to see memory leak
    .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
    .Select((x, i) => (Sample: i + 1, Ticks: x + 1))
    .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"Sample #{x.Sample,-2}, Ticks: {x.Ticks,6:#,0}"
        + $", Memory usage: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true):#,0} bytes"))
    .IgnoreElements()
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .Materialize()
    .Wait();
```

Here is the output:

```xml
Sample #1 , Ticks:    193, Memory usage: 160,048 bytes
Sample #2 , Ticks:    383, Memory usage: 160,440 bytes
Sample #3 , Ticks:    573, Memory usage: 161,000 bytes
...
Sample #49, Ticks:  9,345, Memory usage: 169,688 bytes
Sample #50, Ticks:  9,537, Memory usage: 169,688 bytes
Sample #51, Ticks:  9,730, Memory usage: 169,688 bytes
...
Sample #97, Ticks: 18,509, Memory usage: 176,120 bytes
Sample #98, Ticks: 18,700, Memory usage: 176,120 bytes
Sample #99, Ticks: 18,892, Memory usage: 176,120 bytes
```

The memory used by the program is stable for the whole duration of the test.

Now let's uncomment the line `.Do(x => Thread.Sleep(1000))`, that blocks the production of each tick for 1 second. Here is the new output:

```xml
Sample #1 , Ticks:      2, Memory usage: 166,432 bytes
Sample #2 , Ticks:      5, Memory usage: 173,136 bytes
Sample #3 , Ticks:      8, Memory usage: 185,424 bytes
...
Sample #32, Ticks:     95, Memory usage: 367,712 bytes
Sample #33, Ticks:     98, Memory usage: 367,712 bytes
Sample #34, Ticks:    101, Memory usage: 367,712 bytes
...
Sample #65, Ticks:    194, Memory usage: 563,576 bytes
Sample #66, Ticks:    197, Memory usage: 563,576 bytes
Sample #67, Ticks:    200, Memory usage: 563,576 bytes
...
Sample #97, Ticks:    290, Memory usage: 956,792 bytes
Sample #98, Ticks:    293, Memory usage: 956,792 bytes
Sample #99, Ticks:    296, Memory usage: 956,792 bytes
```

The used memory is increasing almost linearly, by about 150 KB every minute.

Something certainly is going on here, but the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/Timer.cs) of the `Timer` operator is too complex for me to figure it out. My guess is that a [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) is used internally as the tick generator, and its suppressed ticks are accumulated somehow. An average of ~40 bytes are leaked for each suppressed tick.

Windows 10, C# 8, .NET Core 3.1.3, System.Reactive 4.4.1